# Artifactory slow download artefact

Tags: maven, settings, artifactory, slowdown

Basic info:

- Artifactory ver. 4.12.2
- OS - Ubuntu 16

On the server are only installed Artifactory. Connection are directly between my host and server. There are NO PROXY. When I make:

mvn clean install

I have info with a downloading speed and they are very slow
e.g.:

Downloaded: http://IP:PORT/XXXX (235 KB at 0.3 KB/sec)

Downloading: http://IP:PORT/XXXX

This downloading speed taking ages to build my project.

On my host is installed maven ver. 3.3.9 and java 1.8

Below are my settings.xml file

```
      <properties>
        <deploy.snapshot.id>repo</deploy.snapshot.id>
        <deploy.snapshot.url>http://IP:PORT/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local</deploy.snapshot.url>
        <deploy.release.id>repo</deploy.release.id>
        <deploy.release.url>http://IP:PORT/artifactory/libs-release-local</deploy.release.url>
      </properties>

      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
          </snapshots>
          <id>central</id>
          <name>libs-release</name>
          <url>http://IP:PORT/artifactory/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
          <snapshots />
          <id>snapshots</id>
          <name>libs-snapshot</name>
          <url>http://IP:PORT/artifactory/libs-snapshot</url>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
      <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
          </snapshots>
          <id>central</id>
          <name>plugins-release</name>
          <url>http://IP:PORT/artifactory/plugins-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
          <snapshots />
          <id>snapshots</id>
          <name>plugins-snapshot</name>
          <url>http://IP:PORT/artifactory/plugins-snapshot</url>
        </pluginRepository>
      </pluginRepositories>
      <id>artifactory</id>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
  <activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>artifactory</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

Comment: Did you try downloading the same file with a different client on your machine? For example `jfrog cli` or `wget`? What is the speed with those?

Comment: if i get filie via wget everything is fine
100%[=============>]  235,98K  730 KB/s    in 0,09s

Comment: So the issue is with your maven client and your configuration looks OK at first glance. Two more tests that could be interesting: latest maven version with the same settings file, then current maven version with the settings file that Artifactory generates on demand.

Comment: I was doing next tests. I use different host and on this host I used Maven 3.5.2 with Jenkins and the problem is the same

Comment: That sounds like a global network problem... Last test, can you install a local maven on your artifactory server and test from the same machine. I would expect the maven there to be fast, and the blame assigned to the network...

Comment: I make a test. I installed maven on the server where is artifactory and I ran a project. Here is my tests
Downloaded from central: http://IP:PORT/XXX (416 kB at 2.9 MB/s)
Downloaded from central: http://IP:PORT/XXX (4.8 kB at 6.9 kB/s)
Downloaded from central: http://IP:PORT/XXX (12 kB at 14 kB/s)
Downloaded from central: http://IP:PORT/XXX (42 kB at 115 kB/s)

Comment: OK, I would vote for a network problem then, Artifactory returns artifacts fast enough when you launch a client without the network in-between.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your help